# Improve MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

Apologies if I still use MySQL instead of MySQLI. Will be upgrading this soon but at the moment I need to find a way to solve this.

I have a query which I thought is already optimized, which apparently is not.

I have less than 200 rows in the fruits table yet it the query takes about 15 seconds to complete

Here is the query:

```
SELECT `o`.`fruits_id` FROM `fruits` as `o` 
JOIN `fruits_categories` as `oc` ON `o`.`fruits_id` = `oc`.`fruits_id` 
JOIN `categories` as `c` ON `c`.`fru_id` = `oc`.`fru_id` 
WHERE ( (o.fruits_name LIKE '%apple orange%' OR o.fruits_description LIKE '%apple orange%' OR o.instagram_tag LIKE '%apple orange%' OR c.cat_name LIKE '%apple orange%' OR p.price_name LIKE '%apple orange%') 
OR ((o.fruits_name LIKE '%apple%' OR o.fruits_description LIKE '%apple%' OR o.instagram_tag LIKE '%apple%' OR c.cat_name LIKE '%apple%' OR p.price_name LIKE '%apple%') 
AND (o.fruits_name LIKE '%orange%' OR o.fruits_description LIKE '%orange%' OR o.instagram_tag LIKE '%orange%' OR c.cat_name LIKE '%orange%' OR p.price_name LIKE '%orange%')) ) 
GROUP BY `o`.`fruits_id`
```

I'm worried that when the database grows, the search will be unusable as it might take forever.

All help appreciated.

B

Comment: this much of like query will slow down the performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. All `LIKE '%apple orange%'` conditions are unnecessary, they are covered by the conditions for the single words.
2. `like '%whatever%'` conditions cannot use indexes. Consider creating a [fulltext index](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/activating-full-text-searching.aspx) on the affected columns and use [match(...) against(...)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) fulltext search instead of `like` operator with pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

What is slowing down this query is the "LIKE"

Also it's a little bit redundant to search for '%apple orange%' or ('%apple%' and '%orange%')  Remove the '%apple orange%' search.

Answer (score 0):

You're bound to have performance troubles with queries like `%phrase%` over time. Please note that you can use B-tree indexes for queries that don't start with `%`. 
So you have several options:

1. Try to rewrite your queries so that the search term doesn't start with `%` (if your app allows that) and use B-tree indexes. More info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-btree-hash.html
2. Try out fulltext indexes
   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html
   Please note that it was not possible for InnoDb tables in earlier versions. But there's a risk that you'll still run into troubles sooner or later if your tables keep growing fast.
3. The most scalable way is to move this matching logic into a 3rd party app (like http://sphinxsearch.com/) which is specifically designed for that purpose.